# Select along specific train route in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select, route

I have the US intermodal train data([found here](https://arcg.is/bXaPm)), and train station data([found here](https://arcg.is/1mLGyX)). The problem I'm having is that the polylines do not follow the routes. There is one massive polyline that contains hundreds of routes, some polylines contain segments of one route, etc etc. I used the Split Line At Vertices tool, and that helped somewhat, but now I have the new problem of trying to select a specific route, which involves selecting hundreds or even thousands of the polylines that make up the route (after using the split tool).

I've tried using Select By Attribute and using the coordinates, but that just picked from a flat rectangle made by the coordinates, meaning a lot of extra polylines outside the route are included. I've also tried select by polygon, but it was just way too much effort to follow the route and eliminate all the extra polylines where sometimes the rail splits off for better traffic flow.

Is there another tool I can use, either to better split the original data or to better select the splitted data, to follow the route from one station to the next?

Although I eventually want to do this in a script, I'm currently just trying to do it in ArcGIS Pro so I can understand the process.